# Can textview have letters in different colors?

Tags: android, colors, textview, textcolor

I want to display '123' but 1 in red color 2 in green and 3 in black ...
Is that possible, or is there any other recommended way of displaying different text color in the same textview...

Comment: I dont have the code but it can be done using html text

Comment: why that ?? you make a linearlayout and inflate texteview insade has many as you want :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I found it use below code

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html text having 1 in red 2 in green and so on));
```

I dont know web so you better consult someone who can write html for you :P

Comment: tnx , here is something more coplete                                   String styledText ="<font color='red'>asd</font>";
                cache.timeView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText) );

Comment: I don't think that using html is the right way to go.

Comment: Why does the html is not the right way @Kaj?

Answer (score 58):

Yes, you can have different colors in different places of the text if you are using `SpannableString`. Example:

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");  
// make "Lorem" (characters 0 to 5) red  
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);  
textView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

There's a more complete example [here](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring).

[Javadoc for SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Comment: Your answer should be marked as the correct one (not that the one marked correct is not, but I find this one the right approach).

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. The text comes out all black, even though one of the letters should be colored. What does the flag 0 even mean? It's not defined in the Spanned class.

Answer (score 1):

You can prints lines with multiple colors without html like this:)

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);

  Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Your message");        

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, WordtoSpan .length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(WordtoSpan);
```