# How to make different TextView different Coloured

Tags: android, eclipse, colors

Hi there is there a way that in my textview I can make the text in my textview more than one different color? Like some of the text color is green and the other part is red ?

Comment: Pretty much same question here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279441/can-textview-have-letters-in-different-colors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6279520/1278748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Text in my textview more than one different color

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
String text = "<font color='green'>Green</font><font color='red'>Red</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: yes but how do I get it with NO SPACES

Comment: @MikeyBoy I have removed the space between them in above code now try it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might be helpful:[Click here](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)