# 2 different colors for Text in same text view in android

Tags: android, textview, textcolor

I have a TextView widget, as shown below

```
<TextView 
        android:text="@string/inputText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

The inputText is defined in Strings.xml as

```
<String name="inputText">The value of input is positive now</String>
```

Now, I want the whole text to be displayed in Brown color, and only 'positive' in green color.

Is there any way to do so ?
in brief my question is multiple coloring for same textview at the same time

Comment: Have You tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279441/can-textview-have-letters-in-different-colors?rq=1?

Answer (score 15):

this is a dublicate of this question [Change text color of one word in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221930/change-text-color-of-one-word-in-a-textview).

```
String first = "This word is ";
String next = "<font color='#EE0000'>red</font>";
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(first + next));
```

Comment: Oh, didnt see the other one, anyways thank you.

Comment: then mark as answered ;)

Comment: This does not work anymore (tested on 4.2.2 device)

Comment: this should be marked as accepted answer

Comment: Here is an update : 
The color value should not contains Alpha channel !

Answer (score 7):

You could use `CDATA` inside your `strings.xml` to store your string with some HTML formatting, and `Html.fromHTML` to have this displayed within your `TextView`.

strings.xml

```
<string name="inputText">
    <![CDATA[
      <p>The value of input is <font color='#00ff00'>positive</font> now.</p>
    ]]>
</string>
```

Java Code

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.inputText));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this approach: formate the String with html

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>Text with Color first</font> <font color=#ffcc00>Text with Color second</font>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Spannable to do that:

```
String text = "<font color='brown'>The value of input is </font><font color='green'> positive </font><font color='brown'> color </font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);

SpannableString WordtoSpan = tv.getText();

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 23, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tv.setText(WordtoSpan);
```