# Android Textview check word for word

Tags: android, select, colors, textview, cpu-word

i am developing an app for training language skills/translator. Where you have a textview, with an input and an edittext.

After typing i wanna change the color of the typed words and move the cursor to the next word in the textview. My problem is, i have no idea how to "move the cursor" from word to word without splitting the string in the textview to several strings.

[image]

It should look like the picture above. Can someone give me a hint, how to develop something like that.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set cursor position in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035107/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-edittext)

Comment: not really, i am talking about a textview and not about the edittext. I have to change the color of the words, word by word

Comment: I see, does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279441/can-textview-have-letters-in-different-colors